# Zeroth-order Bessel function Python

Tags: python, scipy, bessel-functions

Apologies for the simplicity of this question.

I would like to implement an equation in Python. In this equation, K_0 is the zeroth-order modifed Bessel function.

What is the best way of implementing K_0 in Python?

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to implement it; it's included.  See the docs for the [scipy.special](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html) module, in particular the optimized common ones [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html#faster-versions-of-common-bessel-functions):

```
>>> import scipy.special
>>> print scipy.special.k0.__doc__
k0(x[, out])

y=k0(x) returns the modified Bessel function of the second kind (sometimes called the third kind) of
order 0 at x.
>>> scipy.special.k0(1)
0.42102443824070823
```

or more generally:

```
>>> print scipy.special.kn.__doc__
kn(x1, x2[, out])

y=kn(n,x) returns the modified Bessel function of the second kind (sometimes called the third kind) for
integer order n at x.
>>> scipy.special.kn(0, 1)
0.42102443824070834
```

Comment: `scipy.special.kn(0,1)` appears to be working well in this equation. Thanks.